# How Can I Determine the LocationID of a Removed USB Device?

Tags: macos, usb, detection, iokit

I have a USB "watcher" that loads device descriptors for certain devices, and tracks them in an `NSMutableArray`.

When a new device is added, I get the callback, and can iterate through the list of devices that I have, comparing `locationID`s (unique session IDs).

If the `locationID` of the device is not found (should always be the case), then I add it to the array.

Now, when the device is removed, I get another callback. This has the service ID, which is NOT the same as the one used when the device was added.

Since the device is gone, I can't get a device descriptor for it (thus, no `locationID`).

How do I match this service ID to the devices I have in my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `IORegistryEntryGetRegistryEntryID` to get the device's service object's unique ID when it connects, and use the ID you get when it disappears to match the device in your array? As far as I know that should work. (`IOService` is a subclass of `IORegistryEntry`, so you can use `IORegistryEntryGetRegistryEntryID` on any `IOService` object.)

Comment: Yup. That did it! I LOVE this place!